# raspberry pi headless setup with usb, connection problem

Tags: pi-zero, headless

hello i have raspberry pi zero in my hand that does not have any wifi. i have successfully SSH the raspberry pi to my window 10 computer. but when i try to update the pi, it turns out the pi does not have any connection to the internet, i try to look online for solution, i have check into the device manager but i did not see RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget on the list. how do i connect my pi zero into the internet to get update and install program.

Comment: Have you enabled "Internet sharing" on your windows 10 computer?

Comment: it was enabled but not bridged, so i just connected pi and my wifi, and it worked. yeea

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Note that you could answer your own question (post an answer, not a comment) now that you have figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

It might be changed into COM port after updating. You need to install it manually then. Check this blog for **How to install RNDIS Driver Manually with Driver links in it**. Check this it might be helpful - https://www.factoryforward.com/pi-zero-w-headless-setup-windows10-rndis-driver-issue-resolved/

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved since years. The OP posted in a comment:

> it was enabled but not bridged, so i just connected pi and my wifi, and it worked. yeea – jakson Sep 3 '17 at 22:49